# Differential Backup since a date

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssms

Hi is it possible to do a differential backup in ssms 2014, so that it gets all changes since a specified date?

Comment: A differential backup will be all changes *since the last full backup*. There is no way to say only give me the changes since some other date/time.

Comment: I know you can use the transaction log to restore your database to specific dates if you have it in BULK_LOGGED or FULL recovery mode so you might be able to figure out a solution using logs

Answer (score 2):

Differential backups are backups of any changes to the DB since the last full backup. So in theory, yes, you could have it do a diff backup since some date (if you did a full backup on that date). Otherwise, no. It'll always be since the last full backup.

Comment: Oh so it's since the last full backup? What about since the last differential backup?

Comment: `What about since the last differential backup?` You have to take Transaction log backups.

Comment: @Kin is correct, sorta. Log backups give you any changes since the last Log backup, not the last Differential. There is no type of backup that will give you all the changes SINCE the last Diff. However, Logs are the next "more incremental" type of backup compared to Diffs.